# ImageView issue (Android Studio, Java)

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, imageview

I need the widget's background to be loaded from my database (either the picture itself, or the picture linked to it). After looking at many tutorials (here is an example of what I need: https://youtu.be/mOhNdP1QZ7E), I could not solve this problem. The picture is not displayed.
The java class code is 100% taken from the tutorial above. Tried others too.

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IocPw.jpg)

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class content_scrolling extends AppCompatActivity
{
 ImageView imageView;
 Bitmap myBitmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_scrolling);

    imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.d1back);

    loadimage(imageView);
}

public void loadimage(View view)
{
    imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.d1back);

     class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
     {

        private String url;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public ImageLoadTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            this.url = url;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL connection = new URL(url);

                InputStream input = connection.openStream();
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 1000, 400, true);
                return resized;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }

    ImageLoadTask obj=new ImageLoadTask("http://....png",d1back);
    obj.execute();
}
```

}`

Comment: we're not going to watch that video, include all code here as text please

Comment: put some code in question as text and attach relevant Java code

Comment: Oh, sorry.
Issue updated.

Comment: this is just an example of the code that I also tried. I've tried various options, none of them work. the image from the database or from the link is not displayed in the widget.

Comment: i know this might be out of the scope of what you're looking for , but there are quite a few libraries which make loading of images a lot simpler, you could perhaps look at Glide as an example

Comment: Yes, try using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use a library, which is Glide.

**1. add a dependency to build.gradle (app)**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
```

**2. add the following code to the java file.**

```
String url="https://www.google.com" //add your URL here
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily load any kind of image in image view using Picasso or Glide.

**Using Picasso**:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


Picasso.get()
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(test_imageview)
```

**Using Glide**:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'


Glide.with(this)
.load(imageUrl)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(test_imageview)
```

Answer (score 0):

Glide lib helps me. Thanks friends.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).